# Wordpress - Only Serving Physical Files After Server Switch

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am helping someone move their WordPress site from a (truly) wretched Dotster shared plan to a VPS.

Everything is transferred and working, except Apache is only serving physical files like index.php and wp-admin/, etc... Other directories on the site will return a 404 error.

I am guessing this has to do with Apache ModRewrite, but I am truly unsure at this point.

Halp!

Comment: It sounds like PHP is either not installed, or not enabled.

Comment: lol.. lol.. lol..

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Comment: I wish I could delete these useless old questions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks really like a problem with rewriting.

1. Make sure you copied your .htaccess files
2. Make sure Apache mod_rewrite is enabled (for example by running a2enmod rewrite under debian)
3. Make sure overrided by .htaccess are enabled (AllowOverride All directive in Apache Configuration)

Overrides will make Apache look in .htaccess files. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Hope it helps!

Comment: For some reason, the .htaccess file was overlooked when I scp'd up the files. You told me exactly what I needed to know to clear up this confusion, thanks!